# Codename one creating xml

Tags: xml, codenameone

I am trying to create a simple xml document.

I have never found a good documentation about it, so I just try it like this:

```
Element response = new Element("Artikelliste");
Element artikel1 = new Element("Artikel");
Element artikel2 = new Element("Artikel");
artikel1.setAttribute("nummer", "5678");
artikel1.setAttribute("bezeichnung", "KettenhandschuhXML");
artikel2.setAttribute("nummer", "1011");
artikel2.setAttribute("bezeichnung", "MesserXML");

response.addChild(artikel1);
response.addChild(artikel2);

OutputStream os = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream("test1234.xml");
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
XMLWriter xmlWriter = new XMLWriter(false);        
xmlWriter.writeXML(writer, response);

FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream("test1234.xml").write(response.toString().getBytes());
```

I'm currently getting an `IllegalArgumentException` because of the last line, which says:

> *test1234.xml is not a valid path, use FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() to get a valid dir
>   path to read / write files*

If I correct the corresponding line it looks like this:

> FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(**FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath()**).write(response.toString().getBytes());

But the program cannot know which document is meant??! When I run the code like this, there is no error message and nothing happens and no document is created...

Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream("test1234.xml").write(response.toString().getBytes());
```

should be:

```
FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "test1234.xml").write(response.toString().getBytes());
```

I suggest you to read the documentation in the Codename One Developer Guide, at the page [File System, Storage, Network & Parsing](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html):

> All paths in FileSystemStorage are absolute, this simplifies the issue
>   of portability significantly since the concept of relativity and
>   current working directory aren’t very portable.
>
> All URL’s use the / as their path separator we try to enforce this
>   behavior even in Windows.
>
> Directories end with the / character and thus can be easily
>   distinguished by their name.
>
> The FileSystemStorage API provides a getRoots() call to list the root
>   directories of the file system (you can then "dig in" via the
>   listFiles API). However, this is confusing and unintuitive for
>   developers.
>
> To simplify the process of creating/reading files we added the
>   getAppHomePath() method. This method allows us to obtain the path to a
>   directory where files can be stored/read.

After the fix, your code generates this XML:

```
<Artikelliste>
 <Artikel nummer='5678' bezeichnung='KettenhandschuhXML'>
 </Artikel>
 <Artikel nummer='1011' bezeichnung='MesserXML'>
 </Artikel>
</Artikelliste>
```

I have no direct experience with XML, however note that a [`PropertyBusinessObject`](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/properties-are-amazing.html) can be [converted to/from XML](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/vm-enhancments-full-screen-xml.html#_xml_properties).

Comment: Right with one small correction: `"/test1234.xml"` should be `"test1234.xml"`

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you guys are awesome!!!

In fact, the file was hidden somewhere, I found it. :)

But now I'm facing a new problem, which I first wanted to solve on my own, but well.

Now the generated xml document looks like this:

```
<Artikelliste>
 <Artikel nummer='5678' bezeichnung='KettenhandschuhXML'>
 </Artikel>
 <Artikel nummer='1011' bezeichnung='MesserXML'>
 </Artikel>
</Artikelliste>
```

However, I have to make it look like this:

```
 <Artikelliste>
    <Artikel>
        <nummer>5678</nummer>
        <bezeichnung>KettenhandschuhXML</bezeichnung>
    </Artikel>
    <Artikel>
        <nummer>1011</nummer>
        <bezeichnung>MesserXML</bezeichnung>
    </Artikel>
 </Artikelliste>
```

Thank you guys for supporting me.